# How to use a shell variable to list files from multiple folders

Tags: bash

I would like to run a shell script on files in multiple folders. At the moment, I have the following:

```
#/bin/bash

FILES=("./binBuild/*.c" "./binBuild/subdir1/*.c" "./binBuild/subdir2/*.c" "./binBuild/subdir2/subsubdir1/*.c")

for file in $FILES

do
    echo $file
done
```

However, this only lists files in `"./binBuild/*.c"`. How can I correctly incorporate the other folders listed, into `$FILES`?

Comment: `for file in "${FILES[@]}"`

Comment: Could you explain what that means/why your suggestion will work?

Comment: I had already posted an answer in dup question :)

Comment: If you don’t quote the globs, they’ll be expanded right in the array, so you can quote the values correctly when fetching them.

Comment: Unless there is a reason you want to refer back to the list of wildcards within the script, the trivial solution is `for files in ./binBuild/*.c ./binBuild/subdir1/*.c ./binBuild/subdir2/*.c ./binBuild/subdir2/subsubdir1/*.c; do`... (notice also the lowercase variable name).